# There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:6597/CRMService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address

Tags: c#, wcf

I am getting this below issue any one can help me out from this.

An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code  Additional information: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:6597/CRMService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address.

Comment: It looks like the web end point at your local development machine is not running. Have you started the Visual Studio project (Web one) in development mode? If you are using IIS to host it then confirm IIS is up and running.

Comment: Check Web.config/App.config and change that endpoint to the one that you actually need.